# SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Install - Missing Rockall.dll

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows 7 Enterprise.

When I run `setup.exe` from the `English/SQL2008/Enterprise` folder, I get an error box titled `pcaui.exe - System Error` containing the text:

> The program can't start because RockallDLL.dll is missing from your computer.

What file is that and where can I get it?

Comment: This should be migrated to Server Fault, but this might help: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/rockalldll-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm

Comment: @KCotreau This will most likely get closed on SF.  Questions about SQL on desktop editions of Windows usually either get migrated here or closed as off-topic.

Comment: @squillman I see your point, but the real issue is not the OS.

Answer (score 2):

> SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows 7 Enterprise

That's specifically not a valid option. SQL Server (except Developer, Express and Compact) [requires Windows Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#EEx64).

Developer has all the capabilities of Enterprise, but is limited (in the license) to "development and testing" use.